# Has been and had been for duration

Tags: sentence-choice

Can I say like this?

> 1. How long **have** you been facing this problem?
>      It **has** been for couple of days **now**.

> 2. How long **had** you been facing this problem?
>        It **had** been for couple of days **then**.

Comment: Yes, both look fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are correct, where in the first one you are talking about the situation in the present, and in the second one the situation at some point in the past.

However, there is an error: you should say

> It has been **a** couple of days now.

Comment: Can I also say 'It has been many years now since I visited here'. It has been many years now since I ate this( some food) in this hotel.

Comment: Yup, those are correct!